# Polylang : Display term archive even if no posts

Tags: terms, custom-post-type-archives, plugin-polylang

I use ACF to customize **taxonomy term archives pages** which are in fact **Team member pages**. Pages are translated with the help of Polylang.

Problem is : If the member has no related posts, I can access directly the member page, but the translated page is not linked to the language switcher menu. Instead it has been replaced with a link to translated homepage.

I found that this is common behaviour in Polylang. It is programmed to never show translated pages with no posts.

After some research, if found [this filter](https://github.com/polylang/polylang/commit/a247344a1b3c1ba0e5b70cfe23bf547936ae8c86?diff=unified) that might be helping. It has been added a while ago but there is no sign of it in the Polylang documentation.

Anybody knows how to use is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution given by filter author :

```
add_filter( 'pll_hide_archive_translation_url', '__return_false' );
```